# Reading/writing access violation exception while trying to read data using coroutines

Tags: c++, c++20, asio, coroutinescope

I'm using asio 1.18.1 standalone, no boost. I'm trying to create a client that uses the coroutines from C++ 20, because it was not included in the examples. Unfortunately, I'm getting `write access violation` error while trying to read data with `async_read_until`.

How can I fix the reading and writing for the client, based on the server from the examples?

#### Chat client (the issue is here)

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>

#include <asio.hpp>

using asio::ip::tcp;
using asio::awaitable;
using asio::co_spawn;
using asio::detached;
using asio::redirect_error;
using asio::use_awaitable;

std::deque<std::string> write_msgs_;

void stop(tcp::socket& socket)
{
    socket.close();
}

awaitable<void> reader(tcp::socket& socket)
{
    try
    {
        for (std::string read_msg;;)
        {
            std::size_t n = co_await asio::async_read_until(socket, asio::dynamic_buffer(read_msg, 1024), "\n", use_awaitable);

            //room_.deliver(read_msg.substr(0, n));
            read_msg.erase(0, n);
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception&)
    {
        stop(socket);
    }
}

awaitable<void> writer(tcp::socket& socket)
{
    try
    {
        while (socket.is_open())
        {
            if (write_msgs_.empty())
            {
                asio::error_code ec;
                //co_await timer_.async_wait(redirect_error(use_awaitable, ec));
            }
            else
            {
                co_await asio::async_write(socket, asio::buffer(write_msgs_.front()), use_awaitable);
                write_msgs_.pop_front();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception&)
    {
        stop(socket);
    }
}

awaitable<void> connect(tcp::socket socket, const tcp::endpoint& endpoint)
{
    std::error_code ec;

    co_await socket.async_connect(endpoint, redirect_error(use_awaitable, ec));

    co_spawn(socket.get_executor(), [&] { return reader(socket); }, detached);
    co_spawn(socket.get_executor(), [&] { return writer(socket); }, detached);

    if (!ec)
    {
        std::cout << "Connected to " << endpoint << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        asio::io_context io_context(1);
        tcp::endpoint endpoint(asio::ip::make_address("127.0.0.1"), 666);
        tcp::socket socket(io_context);

        co_spawn(io_context, connect(std::move(socket), endpoint), detached);

        asio::signal_set signals(io_context, SIGINT, SIGTERM);
        signals.async_wait([&](auto, auto) { io_context.stop(); });
        
        io_context.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### Chat server (it's the one from the examples)

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <memory>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <asio/awaitable.hpp>
#include <asio/detached.hpp>
#include <asio/co_spawn.hpp>
#include <asio/io_context.hpp>
#include <asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <asio/read_until.hpp>
#include <asio/redirect_error.hpp>
#include <asio/signal_set.hpp>
#include <asio/steady_timer.hpp>
#include <asio/use_awaitable.hpp>
#include <asio/write.hpp>

using asio::ip::tcp;
using asio::awaitable;
using asio::co_spawn;
using asio::detached;
using asio::redirect_error;
using asio::use_awaitable;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

class chat_participant
{
public:
    virtual ~chat_participant() = default;
    virtual void deliver(const std::string& msg) = 0;
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<chat_participant> chat_participant_ptr;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

class chat_room
{
public:
    void join(chat_participant_ptr participant)
    {
        participants_.insert(participant);
        for (const auto& msg : recent_msgs_)
            participant->deliver(msg);
    }

    void leave(chat_participant_ptr participant)
    {
        participants_.erase(participant);
    }

    void deliver(const std::string& msg)
    {
        recent_msgs_.push_back(msg);
        while (recent_msgs_.size() > max_recent_msgs)
            recent_msgs_.pop_front();

        for (const auto& participant : participants_)
            participant->deliver(msg);
    }

private:
    std::set<chat_participant_ptr> participants_;
    enum { max_recent_msgs = 100 };
    std::deque<std::string> recent_msgs_;
};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

class chat_session
    : public chat_participant,
    public std::enable_shared_from_this<chat_session>
{
public:
    chat_session(tcp::socket socket, chat_room& room)
        : socket_(std::move(socket)),
        timer_(socket_.get_executor()),
        room_(room)
    {
        timer_.expires_at(std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point::max());
    }

    void start()
    {
        room_.join(shared_from_this());

        co_spawn(socket_.get_executor(),
            [self = shared_from_this()]{ return self->reader(); },
            detached);

        co_spawn(socket_.get_executor(),
            [self = shared_from_this()]{ return self->writer(); },
            detached);
    }

    void deliver(const std::string& msg) override
    {
        write_msgs_.push_back(msg);
        timer_.cancel_one();
    }

private:
    awaitable<void> reader()
    {
        try
        {
            for (std::string read_msg;;)
            {
                std::size_t n = co_await asio::async_read_until(socket_, asio::dynamic_buffer(read_msg, 1024), "\n", use_awaitable);

                room_.deliver(read_msg.substr(0, n));
                read_msg.erase(0, n);
            }
        }
        catch (std::exception&)
        {
            stop();
        }
    }

    awaitable<void> writer()
    {
        try
        {
            while (socket_.is_open())
            {
                if (write_msgs_.empty())
                {
                    asio::error_code ec;
                    co_await timer_.async_wait(redirect_error(use_awaitable, ec));
                }
                else
                {
                    co_await asio::async_write(socket_, asio::buffer(write_msgs_.front()), use_awaitable);
                    write_msgs_.pop_front();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (std::exception&)
        {
            stop();
        }
    }

    void stop()
    {
        room_.leave(shared_from_this());
        socket_.close();
        timer_.cancel();
    }

    tcp::socket socket_;
    asio::steady_timer timer_;
    chat_room& room_;
    std::deque<std::string> write_msgs_;
};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

awaitable<void> listener(tcp::acceptor acceptor)
{
    chat_room room;

    for (;;)
    {
        std::make_shared<chat_session>(co_await acceptor.async_accept(use_awaitable), room)->start();
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    try
    {
        unsigned short port = 666;

        asio::io_context io_context(1);

        co_spawn(io_context,
            listener(tcp::acceptor(io_context, { tcp::v4(), port })),
            detached);

        asio::signal_set signals(io_context, SIGINT, SIGTERM);
        signals.async_wait([&](auto, auto) { io_context.stop(); });

        io_context.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Socket gets destroyed to early. One Way of fixing this is:
Do not move the socket into the connection function.
Take the socket in connection function as reference.
This should let your socket life long enough.